# HP StorageWorks RAID 50: Volume size on creation is not precise enough

Tags: storage, hp, hardware-raid

I've got a HP MSA2312i with 24 Hard drives. I created a RAID 50 virtual disk. That makes me a total of 11 TB of available space.

I want to create a 500GB volume (0.5 TB). When I want to create a volume, the web interface does not let me choose the size I want besides plain integer values between 1 and 11.

How do I select a more fine grained size than terabytes?

Comment: Can you try the command line interface?

Comment: Yes I did. Used ssh command without problem. Please post as an answer so I can mark as resolved.

Comment: Yep. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the command line interface via serial or ssh? You should have finer control over the options there.